# how to use the assertion in control flow invariants?

Tags: java, assertion

The previous example not only tests an invariant, it also checks an assumption about the application's flow of control. The author of the original switch statement probably assumed not only that the suit variable would always have one of four values, but also that one of the four cases would always be executed. It points out another general area where you should use assertions: place an assertion at any location you assume will not be reached. The assertions statement to use is:

```
assert false;
```

For example, suppose you have a method that looks like this:

```
void foo() {
    for (...) {
      if (...)
        return;
    }
    // Execution should never reach this point!!!
}
```

Replace the final comment so that the code now reads:

```
void foo() {
    for (...) {
      if (...)
        return;
    }
    assert false; // Execution should never reach this point!
}
```

Note: Use this technique with discretion. If a statement is unreachable as defined in the Java Language Specification, you will get a compile time error if you try to assert that it is not reached. Again, an acceptable alternative is simply to throw an AssertionError.

I found these in Java Language Specs.What is meant by control flow invariants? Why does it need to add "assert false;" statement in the above function block where the control will not reach because of the presence of return statement.
Eager to hear the answer.

Comment: I think you should throw an exception in exceptional circumstances rather than assert.

Comment: What if the control flow invariant changes, and the previously unreachable block is reachable? What should happen? If you `assert false` something *specific* happens. If you don't `assert false`, then the thing which shouldn't happen happens.

Comment: the `return` statement is conditional, it may not happen. but once the whole for() is done and a return statement is not reached, it will assert false for no special reason. Try not to litter serious issues (such as `assert false;`) thru the codebase for no real, explainable reason.

Comment: @bhspencer isn't an assert a fancy conditional throw at the bottom? One specially meant to check for pre/post conditions

Comment: @Shark I think the "control flow invariant" is that one of the items iterated over with `for` is **functionally** guaranteed to enter the `if` and reach the `return`. Raising an error is then necessary in order not to propagate an incoherent state any further, and while I'd rather throw an exception or use the assert beforehand as a pre-condition, I would say this use of `assert` is still acceptable

Comment: It is, until you end up with legacy code that's been failing/crashing for the past few days, and you discover that the root cause of the bug is an `assert false;` added in a "Misc changes" commit that touched 39 files, 2 years ago.

But hey, whatever works - works.